# Why is Observable.Merge() calling Select() on the source observable?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive

Currently experimenting with Observable.Interval and found a behaviour I cannot explain by myself.

```
_rate = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250), scheduler).Select(_ => CalculateRateValue());
_thickness = Observable.Merge(_rate).Select(CalculateThicknessValue);
```

What I experience while testing this thing is that `CalculateRateValue()` gets called twice as soon as I use `Observable.Merge`.
My understanding until today was that as soon as there is a new value on `_rate` `CalculateThicknessValue` gets called with that new rate value. But should not call the `Select` part from the source observable again.

The same occours when using `Zip` or some sort of `Combine`.

Test code looks like:

```
TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
long ticks = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250).Ticks;
scheduler.AdvanceBy(ticks);
...
```

Where every call to `AdvanceBy` triggers `CalculateRateValue` twice.

So why is that behaviour and what can I do to stop it?

---

`CalculateRateValue` and `CalculateThicknessValue` are simple methods returning `double`.
Both observables are of type `double` too.

Comment: Could you edit the question and include the signatures of the `CalculateRateValue` and `CalculateThicknessValue` methods? Also I would like to ask if you are focusing on producing a desirable behavior while using the `TestScheduler`, or you focus on the behavior of the system in a production environment.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by adding `.Publish().RefCount()` to the observables.

Comment: The `.Publish().RefCount()` can cause fragile queries and should be only used when you've eliminated any other cause. Your code as you've posted in your question DOES NOT DEMONSTRATE your issue - it only does a single call to `CalculateRateValue` per tick. You seem to have two subscriptions in your code and you haven't shown the second one. Can you please update your question so your code demonstrates your issue?